# How to exclude particular class from keep class tag proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

I want to explode particular class from Pro guard in android studio. I have multiple class in package.

Keeping rule follows

```
 -keep class !com.example.MyClass,com.example.** { *; }
```

But it not working in release APK and while debug in android studio emulator its work properly.

implementation is related to Bluetooth Connection and print

Comment: `-keep class packageName.subPackageName.** { *; }`

Comment: what is mean by   ' -keep class !com.example.folderName.Myclass.**{ *; }

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code